# Clear clipboard with xsel on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard

I'm trying to clear the clipboard from command line but it doesn't seem to work. Here goes what I'm doing:

Firstly, I put the string 'hello' in the clipboard and it works as expected:

```
echo hello|xsel -b
xsel -b
> hello
```

But when I'm trying to clear it up, it doesn't work because I'm still getting the string 'hello' when I ask for it:

```
xsel -bc
xsel -b
> hello
```

I've also tried with `xsel -c`, `xsel --clear`, `xsel -b -c`, ... but unsuccessfully. Any help?

I know that `echo |xsel -b` is a workaround but I would like to use just a command and would like also to understand the `--clear` option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to type `xsel -cb`  first 'clear' then 'what to clear'

Works on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Do you have some kind of clipboard manager running which syncs the clipboard and the primary selection? Such a tool could restore the entry in the clipboard from the primary selection.

Comment: Oh! Good point! Yes I had clipit running ... an it was definitively that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `xsel -db`. Man pages says `-d, --delete
              Request  that  the  current selection be deleted. This not only clears the selection, but also requests to the program in which the selection resides that the
              selected contents be deleted. Overrides all input options.`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you only want to use one command, then add an alias in your .bashrc

```
alias cc="echo|xsel -b"
```

"cc" is very fast to type and easy to remember.